# Mime type excel and Filter

Tags: excel, filter, mime

I write export data to excel by mime.
How i can set show filter by default in my excel file(created by mime)? Its posible?

[image: What i want]

Answer (score 0):

Given the following assumptions:

1. You have just the 3 columns (A, B and C) that I can just about see in your screenshot.
2. You want to add an AutoFilter to them.
3. You are running the macro for the active sheet in the active workbook.

then you can do something like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.[A:C].AutoFilter
```

This will add an auto-filter mechanism for columns A to C in the current sheet of your current workbook. You can subsequently modify this yourself to target other sheets and/or workbooks; if not, let me know here and I'll try to help further.